# What's the most efficient way to implement thread-safety using mysql-connector-python?

Tags: python, mysql, multithreading, concurrency

I have a Python program that needs to continuously perform write/read MySQL queries from about 20 threads (`threading` module) through a wrapper class.
I elaborated two ways to synchronize access to the database and avoid race conditions or similar issues:

- Use a `threading.Lock()` in my database (or cursor) wrapper class and each class method would acquire and release the lock accordingly.
- Use a database pool. The `mysql-connector-python` module [supports pooling](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-connection-pooling.html).

Which is the most efficient way to achieve thread-safety when dealing with MySQL (both read and write queries) using the module I mentioned and what are the pros and cons of each? Is there another more-efficient and idiomatic way that I am missing?